# Control a large number of LEDs from minimal output pins

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, led, attiny, io

I am working on a project that uses an Attiny84 to control a large number of LEDs. The number of LEDs far outnumbers the number of I/O pins. What concepts and principles should I be researching into for a solution?

Comment: Essentially your MCU will send the data serially.  There are endless ways to do it, not least of which is a basic shift register.

Comment: A LED strip with hundreds of LEDs controlled by one data wire. How many LEDs you need?

Comment: @jonathanjo great, I shall be looking into shift registers. Thank you

Comment: @Justme I will be using around 30 LEDs. However I am looking to discover more about the principles of controlling a large number of outputs (not necessarily just LEDs) using minimal inputs. Any pointers in the right direction would be great. Thank you

Comment: It might be a good idea to also look into addressable LEDs like WS2812. Even less hardware needed.

Comment: See also: MAX7219 (led interfacing chip), TM1650 (also does switches), WS2812 LEDs, and DMX protocol.  As well as basic shift registers, and i2c gpio devices.  It all comes down to the power you want for the LEDs and what else you have to interface.

Comment: How to control a maximal number of LEDs with minimal output pins is a completely different and unrelated question to controlling a large number of IO with not minimal MCU pins. It has a completely different answer.

Comment: @justme Apologies I am new to electronics. I may have asked the question wrong. In my circuit I was only going to turn the 30 LED's on/off using a transistor for each LED as the MCU cannot supply enough current for the LEDs. In theory would it then be possible to switch these LEDs out for another component as the transistor is acting like a switch turning them on/off? Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at the MAX7219, which is specifically designed for this kind of thing, controlling up to 64 LEDs.  Or if your design will accomodate it, WS2812 LEDs, which have circuitry already in them.

Comment: @jonathojo Great. Thank you

Comment: If your LEDs all have the same forward voltage you could look into Charlieplexing
https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your MCU will communicate serially.  There are endless ways of doing this, from the simplest to the most complex.

### With Shift registers

Here's a shift register (74164)
[image]

Basically you connect `CLOCK` and `SERIAL_INPUT_A` to your CPU (`/CLEAR` and `B` to +ve).  and you send your data one bit at a time.  Most of the families of chips will have enough current to drive LEDs directly through a resistor; usually you use the shift register output to pull the LED to ground.  This works well but if you don't clock the bits very fast you can see your LED pattern "ghosting".

To avoid that, you want the data to appear on all the output pins at the same time, and you need a latching one or one with output control,  here's the very flexible 74LS595:

[image]

[Texas datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54hc595.pdf)

Here's a [tutorial](https://lastminuteengineers.com/74hc595-shift-register-arduino-tutorial/) about using it from an Arduino.

### With Special Device

If you want brightness control or very many LEDs, you might use an array and a special chip such as the MAX 7219 or its almost-identical twim 7221. [Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max7219-max7221.pdf).

Here you have very many fewer resistors and because the LEDs are in an array, you can drive 64 of them, and they are commonly used to drive, for example eight-digit 7-segment displays.  These chips stack up, so you can use several in row to make a larger array of LEDs.  (Indeed, you can buy LED arrays with these chips already in them.)

[image]

### With Special LEDs

There are LEDs which take serial inputs, known either as WS2812 or Neopixel.  These take a serial interface directly, as each LED has its own chip to decode its signal.

### Special Lighting Protocols DMX-512

For architectural or theatre lighting, the standard is a simple serial protocol called [DMX-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512).

Comment: "Unbuffered" shift registers ('164) without driver blanking/disable allow severe "ghosting".

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for mentioning it, I've emphasised that in an edtir.